# How to generate HexEncode(SHA-256(Body))?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I need to generate stringtosign for request API. The rules to generate stringtosign is **HexEncode(Sha256(Body))**. I'm using codeigniter 4. This is the example what i've done to generate :

```
$datas = array(
         'hello'        => 'world',
);
$body = json_encode($datas, true);
$hashbody = hash('sha256',$body); // output : 93a23971a914e5eacbf0a8d25154cda309c3c1c72fbb9914d47c60f3cb681588
$hexbody = bin2hex($hashbody); // result output : 39336132333937316139313465356561636266306138643235313534636461333039633363316337326662623939313464343763363066336362363831353838
```

The website who providing the API give the example that the result should be *a47a5f14b3e78b5e3d3f81b1a1468499be964660f818c10adcac792c42709749*

What is still wrong from this way ?

Comment: 1. `hash()` already returns hex-encoded data, so get rid of `bin2hex()`. 2. You need to compare the two inputs to the hash functions to ensure they are byte-for-byte identical, because there's nothing else here that would cause the hashes to be different. 3. The second parameter for `json_encode()` is a flag, feeding it `true` surely does not do what you think it will. Remove it.